# Delete specific document from collection

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

Is there any way to delete or remove document from collection using the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoVue you can remove a document inside the `TreeView`. Just right-click on the document and choose `Remove` :-)